# What is the RIGHT way to use git and public repos?

Tags: git

I have started putting some of my more complicated projects on github to show off to other people. One problem that I have noticed though, is that if I push all of my "screw around" branches, it makes the public repo a mess. I've head that the best strategy for git is "branch early, branch often", but the result of that is an ugly public repo. One way I can think of is to just keep all my branches local and only push on major releases, but that seems kind of dumb (between releases, nothing is backed up!) So what's the best way to safely manage a lot of branches while keeping a pretty public repo?

Comment: Version control is not a substitute for a backup solution.

Comment: You can add the branches while you are working on them and delete the branches once you have merged them into the main branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow a git flow like described in this link.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Also tagging in git may be a subject of interest for you.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging

Answer (score 1):

You can create a development branch where you merge all completed features from your local feature branches and only merge that into your master branch, when you have enough features for a new version ready. This development branch should be pushed to the web.

This way there should be only 2 branches in your public repo, while keeping the advantage of many local feature branches.

Comment: This seems like a slightly ugly hack. If you only want to merge some features, you'll have to dig through history to find where you merged them, then merge the commit directly (or re-branch)...

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce namespaces/categories for your branches, by prepending them to the name. For example, you could have branches

- master
- feature/foo
- feature/bla
- experimental/dostuff
- experimental/funkyrefactor

The Github UI lets you filter branches by name, so people can filter by "feature" to only see "proper" feature branches.

At any rate, I would not worry too much. If your repo has two dozen branches that will not really hurt any one. And if you have more than a dozen experiments in flight simultaneously, you should probably focus a bit more :-).